# Вывести рамку с диагоналями из звездочек Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Задано натуральное число n. Вывести квадратную рамку с диагоналями размера n*n из звездочек, как показано в примере.
Должно работать для n>=40

```
При n = 7:
Программа должна вывести:
```

```
*******
**   **
* * * *
*  *  *
* * * *
**   **
*******
```

Есть неполный код, который выводит лишь одну диагональ:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if i == 1 or i == n:
        print("*" * n)
    else:
        if i == 2 or i == (n-1):
            print("*" + "*" + " " * (n-4) + "*"+"*")
        else:
            print("*" + " " * (i-2) + "*")
```

```
Вывод:
*******
**   **
* *
*  *
*   *
**   **
*******
```

Comment: *«Должно работать для 3 <= n >= 40»* - это влечет за собой, что должно работать для n >= 40

Comment: научитесь сначала отрисовывать крест без рамки (рамка - это всего лишь проверка на 4 граничные условия)

Comment: проблема как раз таки в кресте, рамку сделать не проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так сделать:

```
n = 40

for i in range(n):
    if i in (0, n-1):
        print('*'*n)
    else:
        print('*', end='')
        for j in range(1, n-1):
            print('*' if j in (i, n-i-1) else ' ', end='')
        print('*')
```